# Unable to use performance_Schema in msyql aurora 5.7

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am using  5.7.mysql_aurora.2.11.4 and connected it to tool mysql workbench i have set the performance_schema parameter to 1 on RDS, but when i am checking it on workbench it is showing me performance_schema is disabled.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay7ih.png)

I have enabled the performance_schema in rds, what are the other parameters value I should change on RDS that i can use performance_schema services, I am enabling it for checking the unused indexes in the tables[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gXJZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxmMo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAOX6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWlnp.png)

Comment: Amazon aurora is not mysql, only a compatible service.

Answer (score 0):

To manually enable performance schema, there are 5 parameters that need to be set. You also need to reboot your instance. Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.EnableMySQL.html#USER_PerfInsights.EnableMySQL.options